# How to optimize performance when repeatedly looping over a big list of objects

Tags: java, performance, list, loops

I have a simple file that contains two integer values per line (a source integer and a target integer). Each line represents a relation between two values. The file is not sorted and the actual file contains about 4 million lines. After sorting it may look like this:

```
sourceId;targetId   
1;5    
2;3   
4;7  
7;4  
8;7  
9;5
```

My goal is to create a new object that will represent all unique related integers in a list with a unique identifier. The expected output of this example should be the following three objects:

```
0, [1, 5, 9]  
1, [2, 3]  
2, [4, 7, 8]
```

So groupId 0 contains a group of relations (1, 5 and 9).

Below is my current way to create a list of these objects. The list of Relation objects contains all the lines in memory. And the list of GroupedRelation should be the end result.

```
public class GroupedRelationBuilder {

    private List<Relation> relations;
    private List<GroupedRelation> groupedRelations;
    private List<String> ids;
    private int frameId;

    public void build() {
        relations = new ArrayList<>();
        relations.add(new Relation(1, 5));
        relations.add(new Relation(4, 7));
        relations.add(new Relation(8, 7));
        relations.add(new Relation(7, 4));
        relations.add(new Relation(9, 5));
        relations.add(new Relation(2, 3));

        // sort
        relations.sort(Comparator.comparing(Relation::getSource).thenComparing(Relation::getTarget));

        // build the groupedRelations
        groupId = 0;
        groupedRelations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; relations.size() > 0;) {
            ids = new ArrayList<>();
            int compareSource = relations.get(i).getSource();
            int compareTarget = relations.get(i).getTarget();
            ids.add(Integer.toString(compareSource));
            ids.add(Integer.toString(compareTarget));               
            relations.remove(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < relations.size(); j++) {
                int source = relations.get(j).getSource();
                int target = relations.get(j).getTarget();
                if ((source == compareSource || source == compareTarget) && !ids.contains(Integer.toString(target))) {
                    ids.add(Integer.toString(target));                      
                    relations.remove(j);
                    continue;
                }
                if ((target == compareSource || target == compareTarget) && !ids.contains(Integer.toString(source))) {
                    ids.add(Integer.toString(source));                      
                    relations.remove(j);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (relations.size() > 0) {
                groupedRelations.add(new GroupedRelation(groupId++, ids));
            }
        }
    }

    class GroupedRelation {
        private int groupId;
        private List<String> relatedIds;

        public GroupedRelation(int groupId, List<String> relations) {
            this.groupId = groupId;
            this.relatedIds = relations;
        }

        public int getGroupId() {
            return groupId;
        }

        public List<String> getRelatedIds() {
            return relatedIds;
        }
    }

    class Relation {
        private int source;
        private int target;

        public Relation(int source, int target) {
            this.source = source;
            this.target = target;
        }

        public int getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        public void setSource(int source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        public int getTarget() {
            return target;
        }

        public void setTarget(int target) {
            this.target = target;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this small example program, it takes 15 seconds to create 1000 GroupedRelation objects. To create 1 million GroupedRelation it would take 250 minutes..

I am looking for help in optimizing my code that does get the result I want but simply takes to long.

**Is it possible to optimize the iteration in such a way that the expected result is the same but the time it takes to get the expected result is reduced significantly? If this is possible, how would you go about it?**

Comment: You may want to have a look at disjoint-set/union find/merge find type of data structures/algorithms, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Implementations with path compression are of (almost) linear complexity.

Comment: I would do this in a single pass in `O(n)` time building up a tree of the id to  collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as possible I would attempt to do it in a single pass from source.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by peter on 10/07/16.
 */
public class GroupedRelationBuilder {

    public static List<List<Integer>> load(File file) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, Group> idToGroupMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            br.readLine();
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                String[] parts = line.split(";");
                Integer source = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                Integer target = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                Group grp0 = idToGroupMap.get(source);
                Group grp1 = idToGroupMap.get(target);
                if (grp0 == null) {
                    if (grp1 == null) {
                        Group grp = new Group();
                        List<Integer> list = grp.ids;
                        list.add(source);
                        list.add(target);
                        idToGroupMap.put(source, grp);
                        idToGroupMap.put(target, grp);
                    } else {
                        grp1.ids.add(source);
                        idToGroupMap.put(source, grp1);
                    }
                } else if (grp1 == null) {
                    grp0.ids.add(target);
                    idToGroupMap.put(target, grp0);
                } else {
                    grp0.ids.addAll(grp1.ids);
                    grp1.ids = grp0.ids;
                }
            }
        }
        Set<List<Integer>> idsSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>());
        for (Group group : idToGroupMap.values()) {
            idsSet.add(group.ids);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(idsSet);
    }

    static class Group {
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("deleteme", "txt");
        Set<String> pairs = new HashSet<>();
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            pw.println("source;target");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int count = 1000000;
            while (pairs.size() < count) {
                int a = rand.nextInt(count);
                int b = rand.nextInt(count);
                if (a < b) {
                    int t = a;
                    a = b;
                    b = t;
                }
                pairs.add(a + ";" + b);
            }
            for (String pair : pairs) {
                pw.println(pair);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Processing");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<List<Integer>> results = GroupedRelationBuilder.load(file);
        System.out.println(results.size() + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1e3 + " sec");
    }
}
```

For one million pairs this prints

```
Processing
105612 took 12.719 sec
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed code and answer, it truely is very fast and I think building what I want from the source is the better way to. I did found some peculiarities tho... When I input the example from my question the idsSet contains the following: [[1, 5, 9], [4, 7, 4, 7, 8], [2, 3]] Unfortunately there are still some duplicates. Last but not least I need to give an incrementing identifier to each group like: groupId 0 -> [1,5,9]. Perhaps you can shed your light on my findings after implementing your solution?

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation is slow due to the `ids.contains` step.
The time complexity of the `ArrayList.contains` method is `O(n)`:
to check if it contains an element it checks the elements one by one,
in the worst case scanning the entire list.

You can greatly improve the performance if you change the type of `ids` from `List<String>` to `Set<String>`, and use `HashSet<String>` instances.
The expected time complexity of `Set.contains` implementations is `O(1)`,
significantly faster compared to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You implementation is slow due to the `Integer.toString()` usage.
Changing the type means object and memory allocations. This is now done 4-5 times in the subloop.

Changing it took me from 126ms to 35ms: 4 times faster!

Several other things I see are:

- first for loop can be changed into `while(!relations.isEmpty())`
- the second loop could be done by using an iterator `for (Iterator<Relation> iterator = relations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)`. When you remove an item, you are now skipping the next.
- Place the declaration of `ids` inside the loop

Comment: Thanks for these improvements. I have implemented most of them and they do make it faster. The `Integer.toString()` usage stems from the fact that the relation file is an unload from a database and its not always the case that the primary key is an integer. In later parts of the application I will use the groupedRelation list to check if a record has a relation with another record. The primary key of this record might be a string. Hence the usage of the toString.